# YouTube API - Get live streams by channelIds

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How do you query multiple channels to see if they are streaming at that moment?

I tried to add multiple channelIds in this query:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={channels_seperated_by_comma_and_http_query}&eventType=live&type=video&key={my_key}
```

That only gives the result of the first key

Comment: This question already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454238/how-to-check-if-youtube-channel-is-streaming-live

Comment: My specific question is to query more then one channel in a request without the need to loop and do for every channel a request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Channels:list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list), which returns a collection of more than one **channel**.

**HTTP request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels
```

From the parameter **part**, it will give you **contentDetails** `part=contentDetails`

**Response**

If successful, this method returns a response body with the following structure:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": integer,
    "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    channel Resource
  ]
}
```

Based from [Ibrahim Ulukaya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667899/how-to-search-content-across-multiple-channel-in-youtube-api), you can not add comma separated channels here. Either you can leave it blank to search all channels, or you can have a request per each channel and merge results. There is no multichannel search API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Too bad you cant search for multiple channels without using a loop. My users give in their channel ID and periodically they are checked for streaming. For Twitch accounts I can add the ID's in the query

Comment: Hi Mind gem, you can file a feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Enhancement%20Request)