# Youtube-API-v3 How to search list of youtube URLs within multiple topics and/or multiple channels

Tags: search, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to search within multiple channels at once within the Youtube-API-v3 search().list() function and also search within multiple topicID's.

I have been researching a bit and it seems that since [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667899/how-to-search-content-across-multiple-channel-in-youtube-api) issue opened 8 years ago, and others issues that opened there has not been any improvements on Googles youtube API that can solve my issue. Am I missing something? Or my request to the Google API developers: Could you make this available soon?

If the answer is no. My objective is to look for video URL's that fit certain keywords and are video's of a trusted pool of Youtube Channels. Any tips?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

The [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method only supports searching on a single channel

[image]

No you will not be able to search on multiple channels in a single request.